# iPhone: UIScrollview with Multiple UIImageView with Zoom In / Out effect

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I have a UIscrollview in my application which contains multiple UIimageview. I want to apply the pinch zoom in / out functionality.Code for adding UIImageview to UIScrollView is following

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];
    [scViewObject setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    scViewObject.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scViewObject.clipsToBounds = NO;        // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
    scViewObject.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scViewObject.alwaysBounceHorizontal=YES;
    scViewObject.pagingEnabled = YES;

    UIView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scViewObject subviews];
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    int left=20;
    numberOfViewController=[ListOfImages count];
    //NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (unsigned ii = 0; ii < numberOfViewController; ii++)
    {
        UIImageView *temp=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        temp.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        temp.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        temp.multipleTouchEnabled  = YES;
        temp.clipsToBounds = YES;
        temp.image=[ListOfImages objectAtIndex:ii];
        temp.frame=CGRectMake(left, 0, 280, 365);
        temp.tag=ii;

        [scViewObject addSubview:temp];
        left=left+320;
    }

    [scViewObject setContentSize:CGSizeMake((numberOfViewController * kScrollObjWidth), 365)];
```

here scViewObject is UIscrollview. Please suggest that how can i add zoom in / out functionality

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ADC video that you'll want to watch:

WWDC 2010 : Designing Apps with Scroll views

WWDC 2011 : Advanced Scrollview Techniques

but basically you'll want to implement a zooming scrollview inside each "page" of the outer scroll view and add each image into each of these zooming scroll views.

[Also see the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html) 
[And example code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)